# Use response of the first ajax call to the last ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, promise

I am fairly new to jquery promises.
I would like to ask if this case is possible:

I have 2 ajax calls and I'm using `.then()` to chain the two of them. This is what i would like to do:

```
ajaxCall1().then(ajaxCall1).done(functionCallHere);
```

I can use the response of `ajaxCall1` in `ajaxCall2` which is what I really intend to do.
However, what I want in the finality is to use both `ajaxCall1`'s and `ajaxCall2`'s responses in the `functionCallHere`.

I have searched for similar questions here, and I have never found one. So.. is it possible to access the `ajaxCall1`'s response in the `functionCallHere` ? if yes, how do I do it?
Is it similar to how `$.when(ajax1, ajax2).done(function(r1, r2))` work - like if you put 2 parameters in your function, it is automatically interpreted as response1 and response2?

Also, I am trying to not use `.when()` here since I don't want the calls to run asynchronously or to fork them. as much as possible I just want to chain them. Of course, If it's the only way, then I can revert back to using it.

Thank you very much! :)

Comment: did you tried? 
`ajaxCall1().then((response) => {ajaxCall2(); functionCallHere(response);})`

Comment: for sure, you can call your `functionCallHere` inside then. and also you know you can pass your response to a function.

Comment: Thank you! yes this was my first approach. I was just wondering if there is such a way that you can do something like this:
 ```
.then(ajx2).then(ajx3).then(ajx4).done(functionHere)
```
and `functionHere` can use all ajax call responses such that it works same as `.$.when()`'s `function(rs1, rs2, rs3)` that way it would look cleaner.

but yes, your answer works! so thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do by nesting.

```
ajaxCall1()
    .then((response) => {
         ajaxCall2()
             .then((response2) => { 
                 functionCallHere(response);
         })
    })
```

or you can define variable before all ajax calls.

```
var response1;
var response2;
ajaxCall1()
    .then((response) => {
         response1 = response; 
         ajaxCall2()
             .then((response2) => { 
                 response2 = response2; 
         })
    })
   .done(functionCallHere(response1)); // or other variable you want to pass.
```

one more solution you can try ->

```
async function yourFunction() {
    var response1 = await ajaxCall1();
    var response2 = await ajaxCall2();
    functionCallHere(response1); // or other variable you want to pass.
}
```

note: dont miss `async` before function;

Comment: Ohhh.. The solution I used was similar to the second one (defining variables before all ajax calls). Thank you! this really helped me! i'm gonna have to read about the `async` and `await` keywords before I use them - like I said, I'm entirely new to this concept. Thank you for the suggestions!